# I cannot see the purchased products in analytics e-commerce page

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager, data-conversion

for my ecommerce i'm using woocommerce with GTM4WP.

I have configured Analytincs with Google Tag Manager and all data from website are correctly transfered to Analytics besides one - the ecommerce data (who purchased what product, what was the product price and so on).
I was checking website and all e

```
  event: 'gtm.js',
  gtm: {uniqueEventId: 1},
  customerTotalOrders: 28,
  customerTotalOrderValue: '15.30',
  customerFirstName: '..',
  customerLastName: '...',
  customerBillingFirstName: '...',
  customerBillingLastName: '...',
  customerBillingCompany: '...',
  customerBillingAddress1: '...',
  customerBillingAddress2: '.',
  customerBillingCity: '...',
  customerBillingPostcode: '..',
  customerBillingCountry: '...',
  customerBillingEmail: '...',
  customerBillingPhone: '...',
  customerShippingFirstName: '..',
  customerShippingLastName: '..',
  customerShippingCompany: '...',
  customerShippingAddress1: '...',
  customerShippingAddress2: '...',
  customerShippingCity: '...',
  customerShippingPostcode: '...',
  customerShippingCountry: '...',
  cartContent: {
    totals: {
      applied_coupons: [],
      discount_total: 0,
      subtotal: '86.50',
      total: '86.50'
    },
    items: [
      {
        id: 195521,
        name: '....',
        sku: 195521,
        category: '...',
        price: 21.6,
        stocklevel: 112,
        variant: '250g,,...',
        quantity: 3
      },
      {
        id: 195520,
        name: '...',
        sku: 195520,
        category: '...',
        price: 41.6,
        stocklevel: 112,
        variant: '500g,,...',
        quantity: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  ecomm_prodid: [195521, 195520],
  ecomm_pagetype: 'cart',
  ecomm_totalvalue: 106.4,
  ecommerce: {
    currencyCode: '...',
    checkout: {
      actionField: {step: 2},
      products: [
        {
          id: 195521,
          name: '...',
          sku: 195521,
          category: '...',
          price: 21.6,
          stocklevel: 112,
          variant: '250g,,...',
          quantity: 3
        },
        {
          id: 195520,
          name: '...',
          sku: 195520,
          category: '...',
          price: 41.6,
          stocklevel: 112,
          variant: '500g,,...',
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  google_tag_params: {
    customerTotalOrders: 28,
    customerTotalOrderValue: '15.30',
    customerFirstName: 'P',
    customerLastName: 'G',
    customerBillingFirstName: '...',
    customerBillingLastName: '...',
    customerBillingCompany: '...',
    customerBillingAddress1: '...',
    customerBillingAddress2: '...',
    customerBillingCity: '...',
    customerBillingPostcode: '...',
    customerBillingCountry: '...',
    customerBillingEmail: '...',
    customerBillingPhone: '...',
    customerShippingFirstName: '...',
    customerShippingLastName: '...',
    customerShippingCompany: '...',
    customerShippingAddress1: '...',
    customerShippingAddress2: '...',
    customerShippingCity: '...',
    customerShippingPostcode: '...',
    customerShippingCountry: '...',
    cartContent: {
      totals: {
        applied_coupons: [],
        discount_total: 0,
        subtotal: '86.50',
        total: '86.50'
      },
      items: [
        {
          id: 195521,
          name: '...',
          sku: 195521,
          category: '...',
          price: 21.6,
          stocklevel: 112,
          variant: '250g,,...',
          quantity: 3
        },
        {
          id: 195520,
          name: '...',
          sku: 195520,
          category: '...',
          price: 41.6,
          stocklevel: 112,
          variant: '500g,,...',
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    ecomm_prodid: [195521, 195520],
    ecomm_pagetype: 'cart',
    ecomm_totalvalue: 106.4,
    ecommerce: {
      currencyCode: '...',
      checkout: {
        actionField: {step: 2},
        products: [
          {
            id: 195521,
            name: '...',
            sku: 195521,
            category: '...',
            price: 21.6,
            stocklevel: 112,
            variant: '250g,,...',
            quantity: 3
          },
          {
            id: 195520,
            name: '....',
            sku: 195520,
            category: '...',
            price: 41.6,
            stocklevel: 112,
            variant: '500g,,...',
            quantity: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- '...' are placed instead of real data

In analytics i have enabled "ecommerce" settings.

Why i cannot see stats about purchasement in analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Ilkar.

You seem to be using a mixture of Google E-Commerce and Google Enhanced E-Commerce syntax (along with some syntax that's specific to your backend system).

For example, you start your product list with 'items', which is for standard e-commerce, but use the variables 'category' and 'variant', which is for enhanced e-commerce.

Check whether or not you have enhanced ecommerce enabled.

If so, use the syntax modeled here:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout

If not, use the syntax modeled here:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ecommerce-appweb#measure_a_checkout